# Data Insertion Error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working on a WPF app. There are two problems generated in my code.

1 - when I entered values it assigned 0 to ID

2 - secondly after inserting value when I stopped debugging and again started it, it showed value of Id but it didn't show entered value.
Attached Images will help you to understand my problem!
Let me Explain with the help of these attached images:
Here first image is showing that when i entered a value "assignment12_new", it accepted a value but assigned 0 to its ID, then I closed this window and pressed F5 to start debugging again, Second image is showing result of this debugging, Here value of ID was appeared but its value that was "assignment12_new" didn't. As it was not stored in database. I don't know what' is wrong with my code.

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
 private void dgData_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)  
 {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            //Database context
            DataClasses1DataContext objNewContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            //Creates new object to insert new Record in Database
           Assignment objStudentDetail = new  Assignment ();

            //Check if record is not is table then preoceed to insert
            if (!objContext. Assignments.Contains(student))
            {
               // objStudentDetail.assignment_title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(student.assignment_title) ? student.assignment_title : student.assignment_title.Trim();
                objStudentDetail.assignment_title = student.assignment_title == null 
                                 ? string.Empty
                                 : student.assignment_title.Trim();
                //This will insert new record in table
                objNewContext. Assignments.InsertOnSubmit(objStudentDetail);

                //This will update changes in database
                objNewContext.SubmitChanges();

                //Show message when record is inserted
                txtStatus.Text = "Success: Data Inserted";
            }
            else
            {
                //this will update changes in database for edit operation in database
                objContext.SubmitChanges();
                //Show message when record is updated
                txtStatus.Text = "Success: Data Updated";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like it would be really hard to help you figure this out with this little bit of code. Where/How is the data being persisted? If you look at whatever mechanism you are using for storage directly is the data showing up correctly in there? If it is, we need to see the code that actually performs the change/insert. Not the logic that decides if it should be one or the other.